# Can I use md-select in angular materials to run a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm running into a strange error but maybe I am using md-select incorrectly. I am trying to go to a new page or sign out based on the ng-selected option. Unfortunately, I am receiving this error:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

html:

```
<md-select placeholder="DISRUPTIVE" ng-model="activePage" ng-change="changeSelected()">
   <md-option value="settings">Settings</md-option>
   <md-option value="logout">Sign Out</md-option>
 </md-select>
```

controller:

```
$scope.changeSelected = function(){
      switch ($scope.activePage) {
      case "settings":
        $location.path( '/account');
        break;
      case "logout":
        $scope.logout();
        break;
    }

    };
```

After navigating to the selected page or logging out I receive the error. Can md-select not be used this way?

Edit: It's somehow related to leaving the page without letting md-select finish. If I add a $timeout it works. It's not ideal but at least I can move forward:

```
$scope.changeSelected = function(){
      $timeout(function() {
        switch ($scope.activePage) {
        case "settings":
          $location.path( '/account');
          break;
        case "logout":
          Auth.logout();
          break;
      }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Oh, I added an answer but was for your preview post, not for this one... You should create new post instead of changing the issue completely

Comment: mmm, I don't think that ng-selected should be used in that way, try changing it for ng-change

Comment: Sorry for the change. I still generally have the same issue as it appears what I am doing is not correct. Can I use md-select as a way to sign-out and change pages?

Comment: have you also deleted the parameter that you are sending to ng-change changeSelected function? And use $scope.activePage instead

Comment: I did but still receive the same error. I'll update above to show my latest code.

Comment: don't know if it's a typo or not but in your code it's still ng-selected instead of ng-change. ng-selected should just be used to set the value.
Also, first try to change the redirections to some alerts or console.log just to check if the error still persist

Comment: Sorry, typo. Trying alerts/logs now.

Comment: It runs fine when I set it to an alert or console.log but not when I try to $location or run a function.

Comment: It works fine for me if I call another function. See the edited answer

Comment: Yea, it seems to run for me too when I put in a regular function like you have. When I change the page using $location or run a logout function (which comes from a service) I still see that error.

Comment: It must have something to do with leaving the page. Maybe I can add a delay so that md-select can finish and then leave the page? Not sure exactly how to do that. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's what it is. If I add a $timeout before navigating away or doing anything it works fine. Not an ideal solution but will move me along in the short-term.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I use ui-router to go to a different state, and get the error after the transition is over. AM leaves the md-backdrop at the bottom of the html over the body and the new page is complete unusable. I tried with location, and using notify on ui-router transition see if state change events make a difference, but no luck.

Comment: I went to the line where the error happens inside the onRemove() there is a timeout set at 350, i added a second there and tested, get the same error after the transition ends just a second after. Debugging as we speak

Comment: enough wasted time on this, I thought too to be an issue before leaving the page so i added a $timeout 350ms before triggering the new state redirect, it works now. crappy solution, but does it for us today. Thanks EmptyPockets

Comment: Hadn't hear of that problem before and I hope that it's fixed soon. Meanwhile using $timeout is a hack that I have also had to use for other situations, not ideal but...

Comment: Was any other solution found? Changing state using ui-router, I was getting the error: "Cannot read property 'selectedLabels' of undefined". Problem is, md-select is attempting to call an "announceClosed()" function and it's finding the md-select's controller to be 'undefined'. I believe the problem is the controller has already been disposed in "redirecting". I used the timeout function but I want to avoid timeout's (especially because this has to run inside a very lackluster Silverlight browser control that doesn't manage memory very well)

Answer (score 16):

To listen to changes on the select you just need to add an ng-change directive. Check this simple example

```
<div ng-app="selectDemoBasic" ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" layout-align="center center" style="min-height: 300px;">
  <md-select placeholder="Pick" ng-model="someVal" ng-change="selectChanged()">
    <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
    <md-option value="2">Two</md-option>
  </md-select>
</div>
```

the js part

```
angular.module('selectDemoBasic', ['ngMaterial']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectChanged = function(){
    alert("value changed-->"+$scope.someVal);
    if ($scope.someVal==1){
      $scope.otherFunction();
    }
  };

  $scope.otherFunction = function(){
    alert("in the other function");
  };
});
```

http://codepen.io/Eylen/pen/dobbqg/

Comment: I still get the same error when I try it with ng-change. Is it possible that md-select does not let you change pages?

Comment: This is technically the correct answer to the original question + at least a 350ms delay. I'm not sure what stackoverflow etiquette is on marking partially complete answers. Also, it could just be a temporary hack and we're not actually addressing the real issue.